# How do I fetch correct boolean field values with an ORMLite raw query?

Tags: java, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite with an H2 database in Java, and I have a class with a boolean field. When I use a raw query and the DAO's default raw row mapper to fetch an object of this class from the database, the value of the boolean field in the returned object is always false. (The values are stored as type `TINYINT` in the database.)

Here's an example:

```
public class BooleanPersistenceWithRawQueries {

    @DatabaseTable
    public static class George {
        @DatabaseField(generatedId = true) public Integer id;
        @DatabaseField public boolean curious;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConnectionSource connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource("jdbc:h2:mem:");
        Dao<George, ?> dao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, George.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, George.class);
        George g = new George();
        g.curious = true;
        dao.create(g);
        George h = dao.queryRaw("SELECT * FROM George", dao.getRawRowMapper()).getFirstResult();
        System.out.println("curious = " + h.curious + " should be " + g.curious);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
curious = false should be true
```

I know I could subclass `RawRowMapperImpl` to override this behavior, but is there a built-in way to configure the object mappings (such as a `@DatabaseField` annotation setting) so that `TINYINT` values of `1` are parsed as `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue and resolved it thanks to Kamila, but his answer isn't correct in this case.
You have to write :

```
@DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.BOOLEAN_INTEGER)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is some old issues but may be it would help some one.
Use data type in notation param

```
  @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BOOLEAN)
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same result, in ormlite 4.48 and 5.0. The problem, as far as I can tell, is that the field converter uses `BooleanObjectType.parseDefaultString`, which uses `Boolean.parseBoolean`, which parses "1" as false.